# Custom logic for specific bounded generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm having the following hierarchical structure for `A`, `B` and `C`:

```java
interface A {

}

class B implements A {

}

class C implements A {

}
```

I want to design a generic method that takes in `Set` of any subtype of `A` and perform some custom logic if the subtype is either `B` or `C`.

I've the following for code-block for the above mentioned thing:

```java
public class Main {
    public static <T extends A> void method1(Set<T> items) {
        if (/* condition for instances of B */) {
            // some custom logic for type B
        } else if (/* condition for instances of C */) {
            // some custom logic for type C
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Type not supported.");
        }
    }

    public static <T extends A> void method2(Set<T> items, Class<T> tClass) {
        if (tClass == B.class) {
            // some custom logic for B
        } else if (tClass == C.class) {
            // some custom logic for C
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Type not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to model it in the way how `method1` is modelled (without passing an extra `Class<T>` in the parameter list). `method2` achieves that but by passing a `Class<T>` parameter.

What is the elegant way to achieve this?

I'm aware of type-erasure in Java (and so type `T` will not be available at runtime). Also, I could have extracted out the common functionality in the interface `A` itself and simply call `item.extractedMethod()` which would have avoided the if-else block.

So I just wanted to check if there's any other elegant way of handling this type of scenario.

Comment: The more elegant way is to not use generics. If your method only works on a finite number of types, it shouldn't be generic.

Comment: The elegant way is to define the methods on the interface, yes, and not do your own dispatching via if else.